# trouble installing "sf" due to "gdal"

Tags: r, gdal

I can't install the package "sf" on R. Seems there is an issue with gdal. No idea how to resolve it.

```
> install.packages("sf")

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
   binary source needs_compilation
sf  0.4-3  0.5-1              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?
y/n: y
installing the source package ‘sf’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/sf_0.5-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4073881 bytes (3.9 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.9 MB

* installing *source* package ‘sf’ ...
** package ‘sf’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: CC: clang
configure: CXX: clang++
checking for gdal-config... no
no
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘sf’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/sf’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/1m/w_zt5ygd26n_87h41qf574wc0000gn/T/RtmpNlYbwT/downloaded_packages’
```

Why does it say the download failed, then say the source packages are downloaded. What gives?

Comment: First off, it doesn't say the _download_ failed, but rather the installation. Also, GDAL is a C++ library used for geospatial vector manipulation, with a set of bindings for R. Looks like you need to install GDAL using your package manager of choice, then the R bindings for it, and then this `sf` package.

Comment: Are you on Windows? I would try installing the binary first because I believe that will provide you with gdal.

Comment: No, on a Mac. Unable to install gdal via brew. Not sure how to troubleshoot.

Comment: As of Nov 2019, `brew install gdal` worked, and solved the problem.

Answer (score 22):

Facing similar problem I have followed the steps below:

1. On **Terminal**: `gdalinfo --version` to check which gdal version do you have. Mine was **GDAL 2.2.0, released 2017/04/28** after `brew update` and `brew upgrade`
2. From here: https://github.com/r-spatial/sf, instructions for macOS, as I have already gdal installed, I have used only `brew unlink gdal` and then `brew link --force gdal2`
3. I reinstalled rgdal on R: `install.packages("rgdal", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org", type = "source")` and I have confirmed it was compiled with **configure: GDAL: 2.2.0**
4. Finally, `install.packages("sf")` and it required to be compiled: *binary source needs_compilation sf  0.5-3 TRUE*
5. Again, I have confirmed **configure: GDAL: 2.2.0** and **checking GDAL version >= 2.0.0... yes**

After that, I have the new version installed: 
**library(sf)**
**Linking to GEOS 3.6.2, GDAL 2.2.0, proj.4 4.9.3**

I hope it could be a solution for you too.

Comment: `rgdal::getGDALVersionInfo(str = "--version")` lets you determine which version of GDAL was used in rgdal.

Answer (score 2):

The sf github page has installation instructions that include some information about this issue. In addition to following the steps there to install gdal with brew, I also had to install proj separately:

https://github.com/r-spatial/sf

Answer (score 0):

Actually one simple resolution is  downloading sf file from CRAN, then manually install it.

I have the same problem and solved using this method.