# Fail to upgrade rgdal

Tags: r, gdal, rgdal

I tried to install `sf` in R with `install.packages("sf")`, but encountered this issue.

```
> install.packages("sf")
...
checking GDAL version >= 2.0.0... no
configure: error: sf is not compatible with GDAL versions below 2.0.0
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘sf’
...
```

I got the version of `rgdal` with `library(rgdal)`, `1.2-13`. I tried to use `> update.packages("rgdal")` to upgrade `rgdal`. However, the problem still exists.

How can I upgrade `rgdal` to the newest version?

Comment: The problem isn't the rgdal package, it's gdal itself - look at the error message. The [project page](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf) has instructions for installing/upgrading GDAL on your system.

Comment: @BrendanA. thx. I checked the version of `GDAL`, 2.1.2.

Comment: Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44973639/trouble-installing-sf-due-to-gdal) may be the same problem with a solution.

Comment: @BrendanA. It works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not related with `rgdal` package. You need to install gdal in your computer.